# How to Use Variation on Subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, variations

Hi I have created a variation on my site collection, I noticed that it did not get the subsites as I was expecting, so I added the subsites manually on the Variation Root SIte, however the subsite did not reflect on the Target sites.

So I added a subsite on the variation root site (English)but it is not reflected on the Hindi target site

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please provide us more information like screenshots, URLs and so one? You have problem with navigation?

Comment: Hi provided update on my problem, and I dont have problem with navigation